# Is $C[0,1]$ not complete with the $L^2$ distance?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

$$X=C[0,1]\qquad d(f,g)=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f-g \vert^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}$$
The complete metric space is defined that every Cauchy sequence should be convergent on my book, so I think that the main goal is to either find at least one Cauchy sequence that is not convergent or to prove that all Cauchy sequences are convergent.
I have completely no idea how to deal with the given distance here, could anybody give me some idea?

Comment: Produce some continuous approximations to $x \mapsto \operatorname{sgn} (x-{1 \over 2})$ and show that they are Cauchy but that no continuous limit exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ is not complete with the metric $d(f,g)$. To show it pick the sequence
$(f_n)_n\subset C[0,1]$ defined by
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,&0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\\n(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}),&\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\leq x<\frac{1}{2}\\1,&\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq1 \end{array}\right.
$$
Draw the first ones before you keep reading! This is a Cauchy sequence as a consequence of the estimation
$$
\int_0^1(f_n-f_m)^2dx\leq\int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2}f_n^2dx\leq\int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2}f_ndx=\frac{1}{2n},\hspace{.8cm}n\geq m,
$$
but there are no $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $d(f_n,f)\to0$ because $f_n(x)\to\chi_{[1/2,1]}(x)$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: sorry but I've never seen $\chi_{[1/2,1]}(x)$ before. Could somebody tell me what it means?

Comment: $\chi_A$, or equivalently $\mathbb{1}_A$, stands for the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Indicator_function); i.e. the function whose values are $1$ for $x\in A$ and $0$ for $x\not\in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$
g_n(x)=\min(1,\max(-1,n(2x-1))
$$
Then $g_n$ and $g_m$ for $m,n\ge N$ only differ on an interval of length $\frac2N$ by at most $1$. Which means their $L^2$ distance is less than $\sqrt{\frac2N}$. Thus they form a Cauchy sequence, but the limit is obviously not continuous, there is a jump at $x=\frac12$.